# Path format for .Net application in Linux OS

Tags: .net, linux, vb.net, filepath

what is the path format to be given to read a file in the path.

basic path given is smb:\server address\
in this format.
but while opening the file it is showing error message "the path's format is not suppoerted".

what is the format of the path to rectify this problem.

Comment: give any example for server path to support in linux

Comment: the path is recognized from where the application debug folder exist and not from any drive folders.

Comment: the path is recognized for local server only login user,and not the server path.